# php excel add column header dynamically

Tags: php, excel, codeigniter, phpexcel

I want to append column with the header in my existing excel sheet using phpexcel and CodeIgniter.

I tried the following code, but it's not writing anything in the file.

```
public function write() {
    $this->load->model('excel_import_model');
    $this->load->library('excel');


    $inputFileName = FCPATH . 'uploads/excel/sample.csv';

    //  Read your Excel workbook
    try {
        $inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($inputFileName);
        $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
        $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        die('Error loading file "' . pathinfo($inputFileName, PATHINFO_BASENAME) . '": ' . $e->getMessage());
    }
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('E1', 'test');
}
```

Explanation: I have data upto the D column now i want to make the use of column E, add the header as project_link for column E.
Refer image given below:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function write() { 
    $this->load->model('excel_import_model');
    $this->load->library('excel');


    $inputFileName = FCPATH . 'uploads/excel/sample.csv';

    //  Read your Excel workbook
    try {
        $inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($inputFileName);
        $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
        $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        die('Error loading file "' . pathinfo($inputFileName, PATHINFO_BASENAME) . '": ' . $e->getMessage());
    }
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('E1','test');
    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'CSV');
    $objWriter->save($inputFileName);
}
```

You need to write the file by using save function see last two lines of the code hope it works